# Value stored to 'var name' is never read

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I am struggling a bit with a compiler warning. Here the code:

```
    const char *sql;
switch (fromVersion) {
    case 0:
    {
        sql = "ALTER TABLE abiliator_options ADD COLUMN new_column00 TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'migrated from version 0'";
    }
    case 1:
    {
        sql = "ALTER TABLE abiliator_options ADD COLUMN new_column01 TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'migrated from version 1'";
    }
    case 2:
    {
        sql = "ALTER TABLE abiliator_options ADD COLUMN new_column02 TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'migrated from version 2'";
    }
    case 3:
    {                       
        sql = "ALTER TABLE abiliator_options ADD COLUMN new_column03 TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'migrated from version 3'";
    }
    case 4:
    {                       
        sql = "ALTER TABLE abiliator_options ADD COLUMN new_column04 TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'migrated from version 4'";
    }
    case 5:
    {                       
        sql = "ALTER TABLE abiliator_options ADD COLUMN new_column05 TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'migrated from version 5'";
    }
}


sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
{
    if (sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_DONE) 
    {           
        NSLog(@"Alter statement successful");
        [self setDatabaseSchemaVersion];
    }
    else {

        NSLog(@"Failed to alter the table with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Failed to prepare the statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

}
sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
```

**First warning is Value stored to 'sql' is never read** for all of the sql var assignments, except the last one in the switch (case 5). Case 5 does not result in a warning.

Second warning is **Function call argument is an uninitialized value**. This is for the 
**if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)** 
statement.

Thanks in advance for your hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is because you are missing `break;` statements between your cases.
2. This is because you are missing a `default:`

Compiler tells you that when your `fromVersion` is, for example, 4, whatever you assign to it in the `case 4:` will get immediately overwritten by `case 5:`, because there is no `break`. It also tells you that when `fromVersion` is negative or more than 5, your `sql` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the breaks after each case. Only the last assignment is being used.

Answer (score 2):

Add a break; statement after each case.
Further try adding a default case.

Answer (score 1):

Switch statement Structure:- You are missing "break" and " default:"

> switch (expression)
>
> {
>        case match1:
>
> ```
>       statements
>
>       break;
>
>  case match2:
>
>       statements
>
>       break;
>
>  default:
>
>       statements
>
>       break;
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

The warning is most probably because you're not using `break;` in the switch (you're setting new values over the old ones, without using them).

```
switch (fromVersion) {
case 0:
{
    sql = "ALTER TABLE abiliator_options ADD COLUMN new_column00 TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'migrated from version 0'";
    break;
}
case 1:
{
    sql = "ALTER TABLE abiliator_options ADD COLUMN new_column01 TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'migrated from version 1'";
    break;
}
...
```

Comment: Somehow I went from answering mine to editing yours, I rolled yours back sorry.

Comment: Thanks all. Forgot that the switch requires those breaks. thought they were only required in loops. However, the uninitialized value warning in the if (sqlite3..) statement still remains.

Comment: the second warning might show up because you're missing `default` (see user1186899's example), in which case `sql` might remain uninitialized.

Comment: Yep, that was it, babbidi. Sometimes XCode takes a while to remove all warnings, when correcting code. Thanks.